# java heapify method using priorityQueue

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

I used priorityQueue as a max-heap implementation in my java program. Right now I need to heapify the created heap for calculating the maximum value. It seems that priorityQueue does not implement heapify method. So my question would be is there anyway for handling this problem using priorityQueue? If no, is there any reliable implementation for Max-heap in java that has heapify method? Note that my program use its own comparator. So this implementation should support that.

Some more explanation:

```
PriorityQueue<Customer> marginalGainHeap = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(
            1, new Comparator<Customer>() {
                public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
                    return Double.compare(c1.getMarginalGain(),
                            c2.getMarginalGain());
                }
            });
```

Suppose a marginalGain value changed for "node" object which is a type of "Customer".
one solution would be

```
marginalGainHeap.remove(node)
marginalGainHeap.add(node)
```

but there is a problem:

- It adds some extra latency to my program. I want to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: What are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: So if it is priority queue then you have max at the beginning (or at the end) of the queue ?

Comment: I am going to retrieve update some values in heap and retrieve the one with maximum value (root)

Comment: @Fazovsky Not necessarily, what if a child node updated and its value be more than root?

Comment: Your priority queue should maintain order of the elements on the update. i.e. if value changes then order might also need to change

Comment: I update main question. Would you please take a look at that?

Comment: 1. if a method accepts Object, it will work for Customer too; 2. try to get it working correctly first, then worry about performance (if you change a value based on which you're comparing I would recommend you indeed do remove/add).

Answer (score 3):

A priority queue is already a heap, so it does not need a heapify method.
This method is usually implemented on structures which are not heaps.

So just add/remove elements to/from your queue and just
assume you have the max elements at position 0 (at the root).

Comment: How can I remove that value? first I need to find that value so this process will add some latency at run-time. BTW, what method could handle this situation?

Comment: Look at the methods poll and offer. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: @Alin You `poll()` a Queue to remove an element.

Comment: That's great, except when the priority of an item changes and it has to be resorted. As of right now, you have to remove and then add it back into the queue. This is much more expensive.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov just checking, you need to remove and reinsert the specific item? Something like `queue.add(queue.remove());` doesn't work?